# Trying to tokenize special case sentences in python with nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a Python script that uses NLTK to split text into sentences. The problem I am having is two special case scenarios and I'm not sure if I can resolve it with this Tool. First, occasionally there are characters between sentences. For instance:

```
    This is the first sentence. // This is the second sentence.
```

If I tokenize with `sent_tokenize(text)` I get `This is the first sentence.` and `// This is the second sentence.` The second sentence should be `This is the second sentence.` I could just strip out the slashes but I'm looking for a cleaner way already provided by the toolkit. Perhaps specifying sentences must start with a capital, or any letter. I don't know if there are any parameters I can specify when tokenizing.

The toolkit might not be the best tool for my next issue but occasionally a sentence will have a main title of sorts. For example `Words in a Title: This is my story.` when tokenized should be `This is my story.` I'll probably just have to solve that some other way, get rid of everything left of the colon if there is one, or something like that.

Comment: What's your dataset? Maybe knowing how the data looks like can help.

Comment: It's not really a data set. It is a single description of a TV episode from a network website. The information is not on theTVDB yet. For children's shows, an episode is typically two episodes so the description is just two sentences with each sentence describing a different episode. Sometimes the network puts `//` between the sentences and sometimes the title is included, as in the examples I gave. It's those rare cases that are causing issue. I can fix those easily enough but was hoping the toolkit provided a more robust and reliable way.